# Фрагмент создается несколько раз подряд

Tags: android, android-fragment

Мне надо просто заменить текущий фрагмент на новый, что бы старый не пересоздался. 
В адаптере REcycler обрабатываю клик из фрагмента во фрагмент. 
Все работает но если меняю `.replace` на `.add(R.id.container, myFragment_1)` 
 То нажимая на кнопку дважды, фрагмент создается 2 раза. Соответственно 2 штуки получается в стеке на кнопку назад.
Как пофиксить подскажите?

```
ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener

buttonMap.setOnClickListener(this);

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

Fragment myFragment_1 = new myFragment_1 (); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("_thread", _thread); 
myFragment_1.setArguments(bundle); 

activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 

.add(R.id.container, myFragment_1) 

.addToBackStack(null) 
.commit();
```

Comment: .replace(R.id.container, myFragment_1)  используйте

Comment: у меня во фрагмент загружаются данные с него я перехожу на другой, при возврате получается что с первого фрагмента данные теряются то есть все загружается заново.  А если я делаю .add то новый просто накладывается наверх и ничего не теряется.  Возможно можно как то сохранить состояние первого фрагмента?

Comment: Да. возможно [пруф](https://habr.com/post/280586/)

Comment: Вы можете просто блокировать кнопку если уже была нажата

Comment: Наверное блокировать кнопку это отчасти костыль хотя и решения. Статья хорошая, попробую отпишусь потом, спасибо)

Comment: @РусланЯгупов как правильно блокировать, если была нажата, подскажите?

Comment: Button.setEnable(false) и потом в onStart() Button.setEnable(true)

Comment: @РусланЯгупов дело происходит в адаптере RV. Поэтому тут увы( пока выхода не нашел. Поменял просто на .replace

Comment: вынесите listener в Activity и там контролируйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По скольку фрагмент в моей ситуации сменялся только один раз, то простым решением виделось именно добавлять именно методом add.
Проблема решилась таким образом:

в адаптере или там где реализуется Click

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
                return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            // и дальше действие
            // по клику как обычно.. intent итд
```

Заглушка на 1 секунду. При необходимости можно сделать боьлше. 
Понимаю что костыль , но как есть.